# Python Imap4 server logout issue

Tags: python, smtp, imap

I wrote a python script to check my email for every 10 seconds. Its working fine in my system. but througing some errors in another system.

whats this error?

My python program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import imaplib , os ,time,sys
from subprocess import call



if len(sys.argv)<4:
    print "\n\nEnter required credentials in following format..\n\n"
    print "python mailcheck.py <email_id> <PASSWORD> <time>\n\n"

    sys.exit()

USERNAME = str(sys.argv[1])

PASSWORD = str(sys.argv[2])

MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = int(sys.argv[3])



while True:
    obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.yahoo.com','993')
    obj.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
    obj.select('INBOX')
    status, response = obj.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
    unreadcount = int(response[0].split()[2].strip(').,]'))
    if unreadcount > 0:
        call(["zenity","--info","--title='New Mail'","--text='Check your mail'"])

    time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)
```

Errors is this.

[image]

How can I fix this. help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

The remote server disconnected you.  Yahoo has rate limiting: don't check every 10 seconds!  Try every 5 minutes, at most.

Comment: But I need real time update of emails, is there any way to do this , with out blocking by yahoo mail..?